# Balanced parenthesis in Ruby

Tags: algorithm, ruby, stack, balanced-delimiters

I'm solving the "Balanced Parenthesis" problem in Ruby, and I came up with this solution.

```
def balanced?(string)
  return false if string.length.odd?

  pairs = { '{' => '}', '[' => ']', '(' => ')' }

  string.chars.each_with_object([]) do |bracket, stack|
    if pairs.keys.include?(bracket)
      stack << bracket
    elsif pairs.values.include?(bracket)
      return false unless pairs[stack.pop] == bracket
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  true
end
```

The first check is for the length of the string: If it's odd, the can't be balanced.

I then iterate over the chars of the string:

1. If I find an opening bracket, I add it to an array.
2. If I find a closing bracket, I remove the last element from the array and check if the brackets are a pair.
3. If I find neither an opening or a closing bracket, the string must be invalid.

Are there any edge cases I'm missing? Also, this doesn't seem efficient: First, there's an added dictionary. Second, there is a linear search on each iteration to check either the keys or the values of the dictionary. There's an \$O(n)\$ on the array resulting from the string, as well, but I'm not sure if we can avoid this.

Comment: There's a subtle bug in my code that perhaps isn't work a new answer. At the end, instead of returning `true`, I should check to see if the stack is empty.

Comment: Nice catch! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To eliminate nested loop you may apply regex checking for invalid symbol from the start -- it would be O(n) + O(n) = O(n):

```
def balanced? string
  return false if string.length.odd?
  return false if string =~ /[^\[\]\(\)\{\}]/

  pairs = { '{' => '}', '[' => ']', '(' => ')' }

  stack = []
  string.chars do |bracket|
    if expectation = pairs[bracket]
      stack << expectation
    else
      return false unless stack.pop == bracket
    end
  end

  stack.empty?
end
```

Comment: Having added my comment re ensuring the stack is empty, I'm finding it hard to think of a scenario that this could be possible. Do you have something in mind? I found this out when one test case failed, but the source of the problem doesn't make the test cases public (which is rediculous).

Comment: This one was failing:`[[`

Comment: I'm curious: Why did you use a temp variable `stack` instead of using `each_with_object` like I did?

Comment: @Mohamad, I guess after `.chars do` it would be out of the scope and I'll be unable to call `.empty?` on it.

Comment: True, although technically you could do `end.empty?`--although that's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's possible to check each pair separately:

```
def is_balanced(opener, closer, str)
  cnt = 0
  adds = {opener => 1, closer => -1}
  pars = str.chars.select{|c| [opener, closer].include? c }
  pars.each{ |c| cnt += adds[c]; return false if cnt < 0 }
  cnt == 0
end

def is_balanced2(str)
  [['(', ')'], ['[', ']'], ['{', '}']].map{ |ps| is_balanced(*ps, str) }.all?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Constant Time solution, assuming you know the paren chars:

```
    def is_valid(str)
        characters = [
            '(', ')',
            '{', '}', 
            '[', ']',
        ]
       
        if str.count(characters[0]) != str.count(characters[1])
            return false
        end
    
        if str.count(characters[2]) != str.count(characters[3])
            return false
        end
    
        if str.count(characters[4]) != str.count(characters[5])
            return false
        end
    
        true
    end
```

Its beautifully simple.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: It's also wrong - it returns true for `)(` which is not balanced.